# Porting Android to the new LWUIT 1.5

Tags: android, netbeans, lwuit

I wonder why the Android build was not part of the auto-generated builds from the resource editor?
 
REAL QUESTION: Can someone please show me how to port a LWUIT app to Android using netbeans 6.9.1?
 I have read Thorsten's page and he didnt elaborate on that at all.
I have also checked the other questions on this topic and they do not address my issue.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate [Android with Netbeans.](http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid) Create the Android project into Netbeans with API level 2.1 or more than 2.1. Checkout the latest [LWUIT](http://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show) and [LWUIT-Incubator](http://java.net/projects/lwuit-incubator). Copy the all classes from LWUIT repository and paste into your project. And then remove the `com.sun.lwuit.impl.ImplementationFactory` class in your project. Also copy the source code from LWUIT-Incubator repository and paste into your project. Your main class should be extend `com.sun.lwuit.impl.android.LWUITActivity` class.

Comment: Thanks @bharath. Will do that now and give feedback, so others can benefit

Comment: I am very interested in this issue.
I've managed to import the java files from the repository LWUIT but do not know what files to import from LWUIT incubator, can you help me?

Comment: Just added that files into same package name on your project.

Comment: Hi @bharath I have been able to successfully create an Android version of Shai Almog's Recipe HandsonLab application. I followed all the instructions and steps to do the same for my app but it wont budge :( 
The main error I get is:

trouble processing "java/util/Calendar.class":

Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
when not building a core library.

In my code I use the java util calendar class to create a timestamp.
Please what do I do?

Comment: Hi again @bharath. I was able to sort myself out by deleting the offending classes from within their jars. Crude I know, but it worked! :) Thanks again!